# Convert my php variable array to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have this php variable `$referral_label`

and have this sample data

```
 array:6 [▼
  0 => {#742 ▼
  +"referral": "Banner at Plant"
 }
  1 => {#799 ▼
   +"referral": "Employee"
 }
 2 => {#800 ▼
   +"referral": "Internet"
 }
 3 => {#801 ▼
   +"referral": "Newspaper"
 }
 4 => {#797 ▼
   +"referral": "Powder Driver"
 }
 5 => {#796 ▼
   +"referral": "Radio Ad"
 }
 ]
```

and in my javascript I want to place them in my variable called `label`

that will look like this

`var label = ["Banner at Plant", "Employee", "Internet", "Newspaper", "Powder Driver", "Radio Ad"];`

Im using laravel 5.1

**UPDATE**

My variable `$referral_label` declared using compact and on my blade I can simply `dd($referral_label)` and get the datas.

on the same blade file. I have simple javascript codes. and part of that is `var label =`  that I need to place all these data inside of that variable `label`

Comment: Are you in laravel? or please mention the framework you're on

Comment: I updated my post, im using laravel 5.1

Comment: you're returning this from ajax?

Comment: I updatedmy question

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: just use in javascript  inside blade `{!! $phpVairablr !!}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

In php

```
  $referral_label = collect($referral_label)->pluck('referral')->toArray();
```

And the JavaScript

```
<script>
 let label = <?php echo json_encode($referral_label); ?>
 console.log(label);
</script>
```

Comment: this works sample output of this code is `Banner at Plant,Employee,Internet,Newspaper,Powder Driver,Radio Ad` but can we put something like this ? `"Banner at Plant","Employee","Internet","Newspaper","Powder" "Driver","Radio Ad"` like a collection of array

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel, you can do something like this:

```php
// Controller
$labels = Arr::flatten($referral_label);
```

```js
// view
<script>
 let labels = {!! json_encode($labels) !!}
 console.log(labels)
</script>
```